# Rails password_confirmation being filtered with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, logging, devise

I've read a couple tutorials over the years that say you have to update `config.filter_parameters` to something like `config.filter_parameters += [:password, :password_confirmation]` in `application.rb` in order to not have passwords stored to your log file.  I've also seen a bunch of tutorials that just list off `config.filter_parameters += [:password]`.  I've always used Devise, and I noticed that so long as I had `config.filter_parameters += [:password]` (which is the default in rails 3.2.13), my password and password confirmation are both filtered.

Why is the password_confirmation filtered? Is this a rails thing? Devise?

Obviously, this is the behavior I want.  Just curious why it works this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a rails thing:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/FilterParameters.html#method-i-parameter_filter

Essentially the keys are just passed through a Regular Expression like /password/ and if it matches then the value is converted to "[FILTERED]"]

so fields matching **password_confirmation** or even  **do_not_filter_this_password** would both end up filtered by default.